# Is there a position where it's possible to claim a draw by both the 50 moves and threefold repetition rules?

Tags: problems, threefold-repetition, 50-move-rule

It doesn't matter which one the player chooses in that situation, but I'm wondering whether someone can come up with a game where this holds true for at least one move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can take basically *any* position where the 50 move rule could be invoked, rewind four moves for both sides, and instead have both players move a piece back and forth twice.

Comment: Indeed, since the 50-move rule does not *have* to be invoked at exactly the fiftieth move (only when the last 50 moves have all been non-capture non-pawn), you can just do a three-fold repetition even without rewinding.